# How to Get id's of all inputs inside the form?

Tags: jquery, arrays, forms, input

How to get all id's of input elements inside a form in an array?

Comment: +1 Good question. To those who downvoted: Did you receive the same warm welcome when you were a new comer to SO?

Comment: One possible reason for downvotes is that the title is too long and the question is too short. That is usually the case when they are the same.

Comment: You might want to explain what you are trying to do with these ids, because often when you want an array of ids it's actually better to have an array of the actual elements

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Something along the lines...

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
         // Get all the inputs into an array...
         var $inputs = $('#myForm :input');

         // An array of just the ids...
         var ids = {};

         $inputs.each(function (index)
         {
             // For debugging purposes...
             alert(index + ': ' + $(this).attr('id'));

             ids[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).attr('id');
         });
    });


</script>
```

Answer (score 18):

```
$ids = $('#myform input[id]').map(function() {
  return this.id;
}).get();
```

Comment: +1 - `map()` is the way to go, although if there are `input` elements that don't have an ID (perhaps a Submit), you'll end up with an empty entry in the array. You may want to change the selector to: `$('#test input[id]')`, or at least provide a test like: `if(this.id) return this.id;`

Answer (score 5):

You can narrow your search with a more precise selector : form input *and* an attribute selector for the ones having an id

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form input[id]').each(function() {
        formId.push(J(this).attr('id'));
});
});
```