# Will my code for input placeholder attribute alternative properly work in e.g. IE?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, input, placeholder

I created the following Javascript as input placeholder attribute alternative for [browsers that don't support the input placeholder attribute](https://caniuse.com/input-placeholder), like old versions of Internet Explorer:

```
function placeholder_check(value1) {

if(document.getElementById(value1).getAttribute('value') == null || document.getElementById(value1).getAttribute('value') == '') {
    document.getElementById(value1).setAttribute('value', '');
}

if(document.createElement('input').placeholder == undefined) {

if(document.getElementById(value1).getAttribute('value') == '') {
    document.getElementById(value1).setAttribute('value', document.getElementById(value1).getAttribute('placeholder'));
}

}

}
```

This code will set the value of an input to the placeholders value. But only, if the placeholder attribute is not supported by the browser. If it is supported, the placeholder attribute will be used instead. This code will also only get executed if the value attribute in not set.

It's easy to implement since you only need a specific id for every input and just a small piece of Javascript to call the function like that: `onmouseover="placeholder_check(this.id);"`, e.g.:

```
<input id="input1" placeholder="plaseholder 1" onmouseover="placeholder_check(this.id);">
```

I tested this code a little bit and it seems to work. Since I'm not very familiar with Javascript, I'd like to know if I did everything right? Or, is there something I should improve? Or, something unexpected that won't work on some browsers?

Comment: (Do you have a proper label that explains the meaning of the input field? Otherwise, placeholders are considered harmful and creating bad UI/UX to begin with – https://medium.theuxblog.com/4-reasons-to-avoid-using-placeholder-text-in-forms-8fc33e724e4f?gi=bbeb476ea262, https://medium.com/nextux/alternatives-to-placeholder-text-13f430abc56f, https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/06/placeholder-attribute/ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For who is interested in it, here's the working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function placeholder_check(value1) {

if(document.getElementById(value1).getAttribute('value') == null || document.getElementById(value1).getAttribute('value') == '') {
    document.getElementById(value1).setAttribute('value', '');
}

if(document.createElement('input').placeholder !== undefined) {

if(document.getElementById(value1).getAttribute('value') == '') {
    document.getElementById(value1).setAttribute('value', document.getElementById(value1).getAttribute('placeholder'));
}

}

}

function placeholder_check_start() {
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("form input");

for (var i = 0, element; element = elements[i++];) {

if(element.id != null && element.id != '') {
    placeholder_check(element.id);
}

}
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="placeholder_check_start();">

<form>
<input id="fff" placeholder="Input 1">
<input id="lll" placeholder="Input 2">
<input id="uuu" placeholder="Input 3">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

After page load, this will automatically loop thought all input fields within a form and set the value to the placeholders text, but only if the browser doesn't support input placeholder attribute and is the value isn't set already.

Answer (score 1):

you could load that function with the onload event

```
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  alert("Page is loaded");
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="myFunction()">
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: But how can I get the id of each input?

Comment: you could do a loop like in this post- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2981433/9427950
or you could hardcode it.

Comment: Is there also a pure Javascript solution for a loop like this?

Comment: var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#my-form input[type=text]")

    for (var i = 0, element; element = elements[i++];) {
        if (element.value === "")
            console.log("it's an empty textfield")
    }